# Big Query Issue: Query Failed with Request was blocked to protect the systems operation

Tags: google-bigquery

Please can you advise why we are seeing this error for a query we were previously able to run?

```
Error: Request was blocked to protect the systems operation. Please contact
```

We have tried running this query several times

Writing an email to the address returned:

```
you may not have permission to post messages to the group
```

I get this message when querying a 12TB table with around 25B rows. The query I am trying to run is selecting from one table, with a cross join on another table where two values in table A are between two values in table B, and I am doing a group by on two field. As mentioned before, all was working fine for the last 15 months until yesterday

Comment: according to a Google search, you are the first person to ever type "to protect the systems operation" on the internet - not sure where this error is coming from

Comment: So I am able to run simple selects with where clauses on smaller tables, however when querying a 12TB table with around 25B rows I get this message. The query i am trying to run is selecting from one table, with a cross join on another table where two values in table a are between two values in table B, and round things off I am doing a group by on two fields... hope this helps.... As mentioend before, all was working fine for the last 15months until yesterday

Comment: The short answer:  a cross join involving a table of that size is problematic given any reasonably sized second table.  The message indicates that the BQ team is explicitly blocking this query due to its behavior.  If you need more specific details for your specific case please reach out to me via email (just tack on the google.com domain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your points in turn :

1 - Copy from [shollyman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212435/shollyman)'s comment concerning your error:

The short answer: a cross join involving a table of that size is problematic given any reasonably sized second table. The message indicates that the BQ team is explicitly blocking this query due to its behavior.

2- I think you couldn't email at the address because it's a Google Group. You need to register to these first. There should be a way for you to do so. It's also possible (notice the error message says "may") that your message just needs to be accepted by a member of the group before it goes through.

3- If your issue is recent, it's most likely because you recently added enough data to one of your tables to make the cross join too big.